# Deepstream pipeline for 1 to 3 cameras

Tags: pipeline, gstreamer, deepstream

Anyone knows how to create a deepstream pipeline by using deepstrea-test1 from the API Example and run inference on Jetson Orin?
I get single camera to work and multple video stream, but not the three camera.

I can add code if anyone needs it, else the nVidia code:

> https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_python_apps/blob/master/apps/deepstream-test3/deepstream_test_3.py

And for single camera:

> https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_python_apps/blob/master/apps/deepstream-test1/deepstream_test_1.py